# FirebaseListAdapter - Query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listadapter, firebaseui

Is it possible to specify the which data is read by the `FirebaseListAdapter`?

At the moment, I could only read the complete database. The database holds a lot of different objects. The object has a value which represents the User who has created the object.

Now, I only want to read the objects from this special user. When I try it like this, there are empty list field.

```
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("URL");
    //HOW CAN I DO THE QUERY FOR THAT DATABASE REFERENCE?
    FirebaseListAdapter<Machine> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Machine>(
                this,
                Machine.class,
                R.layout.list_item,
                databaseReference) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, final Machine model, int position) {
                //CAN I DO THIS BY QUERY?
                if(model.getS_UserID.equals(user.getID)){
                   //SOME STUFF WHICH I DO 
                }
        };
}
        list.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
```

The question is, can I do the If-Statement by doing a query for the `FirebaseListAdapter`?

At the moment, I do something like this:

**if(model.getS_UserID.equals(user.getID()) --> DO SOME STUFF**

But it also creates some empty fields which are really ugly.
My Database looks like this:

OBJECT

- -USERID  = STRING
- -NAME = ...
- -.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in a `Query` to the `FirebaseListAdapter` instead of the database reference you use right now. To filter on items with the user ID:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("URL");
Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("s_UserId").equalTo(user.getID);

FirebaseListAdapter<Machine> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Machine>(
            this,
            Machine.class,
            R.layout.list_item,
            query) {
```

Read more about this in the [Firebase documentation on ordering and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

Comment: Hello Frank could you give me a example for that? You are a fantastic programmer which i follow at GitHub too. You have a project which includes a own Adapter. Could you give also an example for this?